# Variável na consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Galera, estou tentando fazer uma consulta com uma variável que estou recebendo, porém não está funcionando. Alguma sugestão ?

```
$model = $_REQUEST['model'];
$customer = $_REQUEST['customer'];
SELECT * FROM sistema WHERE concluido <> 1 AND site='$site' AND $model='X'
```

Comment: Qual o erro? E estas variáveis estão vindas corretamente?

Comment: Está muito confuso isso. Você não está a usar  o $customer, em vez disso está usando $site. Não entendi se a string sql esta assim mesmo e se você não sabe fazer consulta no banco ou se foi só de exemplo...

Comment: Tentou imprimir a consulta e executar direto no banco?

Comment: Espero que `$model` não seja o que parece...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elabore da seguinte forma:

```
$model = $_REQUEST['model'];
$customer = $_REQUEST['customer'];

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM sistema WHERE concluido <> 1 AND site = '{$site}' AND {$model} = 'X'";
```

Não esqueça de verificar se as variáveis estão vindas corretamente e se realmente o sinal de comparação é `<>`, talvez você posa usar `= '1'`.

Comment: Sensacional André, Obrigado amigo!!